# Override Maven's default resource filter replacement pattern

Tags: maven-2, filtering

By default maven will filter resources like this:

```
<properties>
  <replace.me>value</replace.me>
</properties>

<some-tag>
  <key>${replace.me}</key>
</some-tag>
```

will get you:

```
<some-tag>
  <key>value</key>
</some-tag>
```

Is there a way to override the way maven selects the strings to replace? Specifically, I want to be able to use this:

```
<some-tag>
  <key>@replace.me@</key>
</some-tag>
```

to get the same result as above.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Have a look at the [`delimiters`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/resources-mojo.html#delimiters) parameter of the resources mojo. Configuring the plugin like this will do the trick:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.4.2</version>
  <configuration>
    <delimiters>
     <delimiter>${*}</delimiter><!-- to keep the default behavior -->
     <delimiter>@</delimiter><!-- to add Ant-like tokens style -->
    </delimiters>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 17):

If you would like to use only one approach then disable default delimeters:

```
<useDefaultDelimiters>false</useDefaultDelimiters>
<delimiters>
  <delimiter>@</delimiter>
</delimiters>
```

Comment: +1, would be nice if official docs told you even when defining your own you still had to turn off the default ones.