# How to add a build timestamp to the title of an application built with Tycho

Tags: maven, eclipse-rcp, tycho

Is there a way to have the product name, which is shown in the title of the started application, set by the Tycho build?

Currently, the title of my application is the static product name set in the product configuration file. However I want to add a build number or timestamp to that title to better distinguish the different builds of the application.

So instead of `My Application`, I would like to have `My Application (<buildNr>-<date>)` with the build number and date expanded.

If this is not possible with Tycho, any other solution is welcome.

Comment: Not sure how to do it in Tycho, but we are usually storing version in version.properties file and then updating application title programmatically. For example, in ApplicationWorkbenchWindowAdvisor

Comment: If Tycho can't do it directly, you still have the thousands of other Maven plug-ins that can be integrated with the Tycho build. In your case the `maven-resources-plugin` will probably help.

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure if it is an ideal solution but I did the following:

To properly set the application title the product name has to be set, as it is also used in the `About <productName>`-menu item, furthermore it is returned when `Platform.getProduct().getName()` is called. (Which is used sometimes in my legacy product.)

To set the product name while building I do the following:

1. read the product name from the `plugin.properties` file
2. modify the `plugin.properties` with Tycho (Maven)

**1. Read the product name from the `plugin.properties` file**

To make it easier to modify the product name via Maven, that String is externalized to `plugin.properties`.

In the plugin configuration file and in the `plugin.xml`, the product name should be set to `%product.name`.

[image]

Then in the `plugin.properties` add the following line:

```
product.name=@productName@
```

If you start your product now, the application title should be `@productName@`.

**2. Modify the `plugin.properties` with Tycho (Maven)**

To change `@productName@` to the desired text the Maven [filtering](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html) is used. Eclipse can not start the product anymore if the standard filter delimiters (`${productName}`) are used, therefore I use the Ant like delimiters. This snippet needs to be added to the pom:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.3</version>
    <configuration>
            <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            <delimiters>
                <delimiter>${*}</delimiter><!-- to keep the default behavior -->
                <delimiter>@</delimiter><!-- to add Ant-like tokens style, this is needed as RCP has problems with the accolades -->
            </delimiters>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I found this solution [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2315009/override-mavens-default-resource-filter-replacement-pattern).

To replace `@productName@` with the actual value the Maven property `<productName>` has to be defined in the pom:

```
<properties>
    <productName>MyApp_${maven.build.timestamp}</productName>
</properties>
```

`<productName>` can contain any value e.g. `${buildNumber}` from the [Build Number Maven Plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/buildnumber-maven-plugin/index.html).

Now the the only missing part is the following snippet which activates the filtering:

```
<resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>./</directory>
        <includes>
            <include>plugin.properties</include>
        </includes>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
    </resource>
</resources>
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing your solution. Looks good - in particular because you don't need to add any code in your application.